# Binding datatable to an rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, rdlc

I have used Data set to bind my rdlc reports using my Stored Procedure. Can I bind a manipulated data table to my rdlc report instead of Data set(.xsd).

Comment: You can bind without dataset, but you wont be able to design the report using the visual tool because reportviewer would have no idea about the fields

Comment: @meda : How can I do that.? I am new to rdlc. Please can you provide me with a link

Comment: see my answer let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reportViewer on ASPX

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" SizeToReportContent="True">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Method to get data set

```
private DataTable GetSPResult()
{
    DataTable ResultsTable = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("yourStorePorcedure", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ResultsTable);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    return ResultsTable;
}
```

Bind result to reportviewer

```
DataTable dt = GetSPResult();
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt));
```

Add DataSet to your Project, then add a tableadapter to it:

[image]

Go through the wizard and create the entity using the store procedure

Then Make sure the DataSet file is added to your rdlc

[image]

Now you need to design , and add the fields or it will be blank

Comment: My report is not getting bind. Datset1 should be changed to something..??? report is blank.

Comment: @Ankur I added more info

Comment: which fields I need to add. The one that I am taking in my datatable.?

Comment: Yes the same one,Then  from toolbox drag a table or matrix, then you can select the fields

Comment: Which SP I should add when i add the Dataset(.xsd).??

Comment: I dont have the same fields in my Stored Procedure. I have manipulated the data table by taking values from different Stored Procedures.

Comment: this is more complex, either post a new question show more info, but I recommend you to manipulate all your data inside of your database, or bundle your storedprocedure into a single one

Answer (score 4):

Yes we can use manipulated datatable as datasource to report.but the field name should be       same.

```
DataTable   dtReportData="yourdata source"

YourReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportDataSource RDS1 = new ReportDataSource("SampleReport", dtReportData);
YourReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
YourReportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
YourReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Your Report Path";
YourReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS1);
```

Comment: I got the following error 


    An error occurred during local report processing.
        The report definition for report '/TEST' has not been specified.Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: How should be my report design.? According to the table that I am going to bind because here we are not having any .xsd file.